# NestJS Kafka Rebalance & Partition Assignment Strategies, what will happen to already running tasks?

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka, nestjs, kafkajs

Let's imagine we have:

- 1 Kafka broker
- 1 topic, 10 partitions
- 1 NestJS producer
- changing number of NestJS consumers (from 1 to 10)

After a while, when number of consumers changes, Kafka initiates a rebalancing. AFAIK, NestJS has its own implementation of the assignment stategy, but I didn't find it in the official documentation.
What will happen to already running tasks?
Will they be executed in vain?
Or maybe there is some way to handle it?
Thanks.

I tried the setup described above on my computer, and it looks like NestJS is waiting for the consumer to process its message, and only after that rebalancing occurs.

Answer (score 0):

NestJS uses KafkaJS, so the documentation [would be there](https://kafka.js.org/docs/consuming#custom-partition-assigner) and you can [instrument](https://kafka.js.org/docs/instrumentation-events#consumer) a stop/rebalance listener to handle those events.

In my experience, rebalancing does not wait for consumers to complete; rather, the consumer group coordinator will signal for them to be terminated.